# What does a double dollar with parentheses and braces following mean in TCL?

Tags: tcl

### Question

What does the following line do?

```
eval "set abc \$${SID}(abc)"
```

### My try

I know that `$someArray(index)` is how arrays are accessed in TCL.
So

```
set abc $SID(abc)
```

would expect `abc` to be a key of the array `SID` (as far as I know `abc` could be anything as all arrays in TCL are associative. Is this correct?). Then it assigns the value to `abc`.

So in Pseudocode that line does

```
Ensure: SID is array, abc exists

abc <- SID[abc]
```

But why are there braces around `SID`? Why the `eval`?

Comment: Those aren't braces (`{ }`) but parentheses, and in this case they seem to be a part of the variable's name.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brackets), `{ }` are called "Braces" or "curly brackets". But I had an error in my question as well. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Oh bummer. I should have refreshed before posting my answer... Oops

Comment: @Jerry: I'm really sorry for that! As soon as I've realized that I've made this mistake, I've fixed it.

Comment: @moose: yeah, that's what I said.  `{ }` are braces, `( )` are parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braces are used to prevent substitution of variables of more characters than necessary.

```
$variableonetwo
```

Refers to a variable named `variableonetwo` and returns its value:

```
% set variableonetwo 1
% puts $variableonetwo
1
```

But...

```
${variableone}two
```

Refers to the variable named `variableone` and the string `two`:

```
% set variableone 1
% puts ${variableone}two
1two
% puts $variableonetwo
can't read "variableonetwo": no such variable
```

---

`eval` is used to... well evaluate/execute a command.

```
eval "set abc \$${SID}(abc)"
```

Will try to evaluate the following if `$SID` has the value `foo` which is an array.

```
set abc $foo(abc)
```

An advantage of using `eval` here is that you are able to have not one but *two* substitutions in the same line, the first being substituting `$SID` to an array name and the second being from the array value (from the provided key).

Comment: I've made an error in the line of code. It's `eval "set abc \$${SID}(abc)"` and not `eval "set abc \$$(SID)(abc)"`. Sorry.

Comment: @moose On the plus side, I did include `\$${SID}(abc)` in my answer, lol.

Comment: Ok, so do I understand it correct that it does what I've written in pseudocode in my question?

Comment: @moose I edited my answer to make it more on-topic. I wouldn't say that it ensures that `SID` is array and that `abc` exists, because the code snippet fails if either of them doesn't exist. A safeguard for the non-existence of those two I can think of would be to use `catch` instead: `catch {eval "set abc \$${SID}(abc)"}`.

Comment: why use eval inside catch? `catch "set abc \$${SID}(abc)"` does the same.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Uh... I did that because of the double substitution (and I'm not entirely familiar with `eval` that much). And here, would it even run when the script will try substituting `${SID}`? We're not using braces so substitution happens.

Comment: The only thing to note: the double-eval is usually a bad idea. Better to use `upvar 0` to make a local alias and assign via that.