# How tcl curly braces in ${variableName} is interpreted?

Tags: tcl

I am a newbie in TCL Programming. I was having confusion about curly braces, answer to this question [tcl curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193641/tcl-curly-braces) cleared most of my doubts. 
I can understand  `$var`, `{var}`, and `{$var}`, But recently I came across another use of curly braces, `${var}`. How is this interpreted by TCL?
I have seen this is used when accessing variables in namespaces when namespaces name is in variable.

for example:

```
set x myNamespace   ;#myNamespace is name of namespace 
puts [set ${x}::var1] ;#var1 is variable in the namespace
```

It gives error when you don't use curly braces around 'x'.

And I also don't understand the difference between `{a b c}` and `[list a b c]`, what is the difference in result of interpretation of these two commands by TCL interpretation.

elaborated explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21387543/1578604). The question is not phrased the same, but the main underlying issue is. Also, I also explained the braces [in this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22332741/1578604) at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See rule 8 of [the manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm). It allows you to have variable names that might get mis-interpreted. For instance:

```
% set dotted.name 1
1
% puts $dotted.name
can't read "dotted": no such variable
% puts ${dotted.name}
1
```

Read section 8 carefully as it actually explains all this quite explicitly.

**Update to answer edited question**

In the example you provide using a namespace name in a variable you must consider section 8 part 1: a variable name includes letters, digits, underscores and namespace separators. This means that `x::var1` is a valid variable name. So `$x::var1` will attempt to dereference the `var1` variable in the `x` namespace. As this is not what you meant, you must dereference your `x` variable separately. There are two ways to do this. You can either use the `set` command or the dollar operator.

```
set x myNamespace
puts [set ${x}::var1]
puts [set [set x]::var1]
```

The two puts statements are equivalent here with the second version showing an explicit separate pass to obtain the value of the `x` variable which is then substituted into the expression for the outer `set` command. The same occurs in the first version but just uses the grouping operator to restrict the effect of the dollar to the `x` variable name.

Comment: But why it is not working without braces in the code I have mentioned in the question? I don't have dot in the namespace name. Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the curly braces then you're effectively doing `[set ${x::var1}]`. In a way, it's the opposite of the dot problem in that tcl recognize `::` as a variable name character and therefore interprets the whole `x::var1` as a single variable name.